# Can i host only a python script directly on heroku without putting the script inside a django app?

Tags: python, django

i have a python script that needs to run on the heroku but its a pure python script and not a django app yet, so i wondering if i can run python script on heroku without putting it into a django app .

I already have the script on heroku but i dont know how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Heroku CLI" for login

cmd :-  heroku login

then go to the path where your script resides, then execute the cmd with your script file name

Example : - if your script name is newfile.py, then

cmd :- python newfile.py

make sure, you have called your function in

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # function call to execute
    main()
```

Comment: how do i get into heroku cmd to run python newfile.py